# With set -e, is it possible to ignore errors for certain commands?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that I want to globally enable set -e.

But rather than disable it and reenable it all the time, I'm wondering if there is a way of selectively disabling error handling just sometimes.
For example, commands run from systemd can be preceeded by a minus to ignore errors.  Does bash has an equivalent?

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

WAN_IF=eth2

# Ignore error on next line
tc qdisc del dev ${WAN_IF} root

# I want errors to stop the script on this line
tc qdisc add dev ${WAN_IF} root handle 1: htb default 10

...
etc
```

Because of the need to enable/disable a lot I don't want to have to keep doing the following:

```
set +e
tc qdisc del dev ${WAN_IF} root

# I want errors to stop the script on this line
set -e
tc qdisc add dev ${WAN_IF} root handle 1: htb default 10
...
```

Comment: Instead of explicit `set -e`, I would recommend this: `old_set=$-; set +e; <code_returning_exit!=0>; set -$old_set`. Just in case `set -e` is not already set, you don't want to set it unnecessarily. functions are re-usable. So they may be called in a case when `set -e` is not set. This precaution may not be required in a script, but in interactive shells, it may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner - would you like to put that into an answer so others can see it.  It works perfectly.

Comment: The problem with `set -e` isn't that you have to be careful about which commands you want to allow to fail. The problem is that it doesn't compose. If someone else reads this post and uses `source yourfile || :` to source this script while allowing failure, suddenly `yourfile` will no longer stop on errors *anywhere*. Not even on failing lines after an explicit `set -e`.

Comment: This thread on [superuser: How to disable set -e for an individual command?](https://superuser.com/a/1458830/317140) has better answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `|| :` (or anything else that is guaranteed not to fail but that's the simplest) to the end of the command.

Though many people would simply tell you that `set -e` isn't worth it because it isn't as useful as you might think (and causes issues like this) and manual error checking is a better policy.

(I'm not in that camp yet though the more I run into issues like this the more I think I might get there one day.)

From thatotherguy's comment explaining one of major the issues with `set -e`:

> The problem with `set -e` isn't that you have to be careful about which commands you want to allow to fail. The problem is that it doesn't compose. If someone else reads this post and uses `source yourfile || :` to source this script while allowing failure, suddenly `yourfile` will no longer stop on errors anywhere. Not even on failing lines after an explicit `set -e`.

Comment: Seeing as no one will be using my script for anything other than its intended purpose I'm fine with the limitations.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`||:` is ambiguous about what it's doing. Future code readers or future you might be confused. How about an explicit echo:

```
some_command_allowed_to_fail || (echo "this echo is just to \
    disable the error status" > /dev/null)
```

(Edit: add `>/dev/null` to avoid unnecessary showing the message to the user)

Comment: A comment about ||: removes the  ambiguity.  That's what they are for.

Comment: Why not just use || true then... Why add a whole new line for a comment @hookenz...